# Meta site help documents are not specific to Meta

Tags: support, meta, help-center

Backstory

I had a question I was considering asking on SO.  Then I realized it wasn't a good fit for SO, and was going to ask here on Meta as to what site (SE or otherwise) would be the best place to ask.  But I wasn't sure if that kind of question was appropriate for Meta either.

Problem

The links to the Help Center, both in the help dropdown menu at the top and the help link in the footer, have `meta.stackoverflow.com/help` as the URL, but they redirect to `stackoverflow.com/help`.  The latter contains useful information about what kinds of questions are appropriate for SO, but I was looking for info about what kinds of questions are appropriate for Meta.

Do such pages exist?  The closest I could find is `http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta`.  How do users new to SO Meta know what's ok to ask on SO Meta?

Comment: Beyond what you already found, the best I have to offer is [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only help page about what's OK to ask on meta is the one you found. As for where to ask about what SE site is appropriate for a question, you want [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). Note: That Meta site has its own rep system so votes there actually count, unlike SO's meta.

Comment: Err... none of the duplicates accurately answer the question as posed: where is the meta specific documentation in the help center.

Comment: @Braiam Did you read my linked question? I already asked about that.

Comment: @Laurel "I was looking for info about what kinds of questions are appropriate for Meta." "How do users new to Meta know what's ok to ask on Meta?" That seems to be the main points of this questions and none of the duplicates specifically address neither. Yours is more a complain that mso/help shouldn't link so/help.

Comment: @Braiam Let me quote from my question: `Where am I supposed to go to get help writing on meta?`